# No wifi adapter found after updating to kernel 5.4.13 in my HP 15-bs 145TU lapotop with ubuntu 18.04

Tags: drivers, wireless, kernel

After I updated the kernel of my laptop to 5.4.13, No wifi adapter is found. So I tried the following steps:

```
sudo apt remove bcmwl-kernel-source && sudo apt install git dkms
git clone -b extended https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new.git
sudo dkms add ./rtlwifi_new
sudo dkms install rtlwifi-new/0.6
```

But the fourth step shows the following errors :

```
Kernel preparation unnecessary for this kernel.  Skipping...
Building module:
cleaning build area.....(bad exit status: 2)
make -j8 KERNELRELEASE=5.4.13-050413-generic -C /lib/modules/5.4.13-050413-generic/build M=/var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build.......(bad exit status: 2)
ERROR (dkms apport): binary package for rtlwifi-new: 0.6 not found
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 5.4.13-050413-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.6/build/make.log for more information.**
```

Please help. It's being very difficult for me to work without wifi.
Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: @guiverc That's not true. The 5.4.0-9 kernel is the one used in the development 20.04 branch. It can't be cosidered as stable. It is based on the 5.4.x stable mainline one. OP got the kernel most likeley from https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/ but that doesn't make those kernels Ubuntu kernels or stable for use with Ubuntu.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ubuntu doesn't use mainline Linux kernels. `dkms` drivers like `bcmwl-kernel-source` (Broadcom wirleless drivers) in Ubuntu repositories are supposed to build against Ubuntu kernels, not the mainline ones.

You installed a mainline unsupported kernel. Wi-Fi stopped working, that was predictable.

Then you removed a Broadcom driver and installed a Realtek driver for some reason. What did you expect to happen?

Broadcom proprietary drivers won't work on an unsuppoted kernel. Drivers from a completely different device won't help in any way.

`rtlwifi_new` won't build on the 5.4 kernel for the same reason.

The solution is to boot with an Ubuntu supported 5.3 kernel using grub menu and install `bcmwl-kernel-source` back if you have a Broadcom device.

Comment: Thank you very much for your replies. The solution that worked me is the down gradation of kernel to 4.14. Just after downgrading the kernel to 4.14 and  rebooting solved the wifi issue. worked

Comment: Upgrading to the most stable kernel (Linux 5.10.1-051001-lowlatency), resolved all the issues. Bluetooth as well as wifi is working good.

Answer (score 0):

I did something similar to what Pilot6 says, but without downgrading (at least not a major/minor version downgrade).

I saw I had kernel `5.4.0-1025-gcp` installed by running `uname -r`.

I ran `sudo apt remove linux-image-5.4.0-1025-gcp` and `sudo apt remove linux-headers-5.4.0-1025-gcp`.

Then I ran `sudo apt install linux-generic` to get the latest generic kernel.

I then rebooted with this kernel (`5.4.0-48-generic`).

Then `sudo apt remove bcmwl-kernel-source` and `sudo apt purge bcmwl-kernel-source`.

Finally `sudo apt install bcmwl-kernel-source`. It installed correctly for the generic header and now my wifi is working.

Comment: Upgrading to the most stable kernel (Linux 5.10.1-051001-lowlatency), resolved all the issues. Bluetooth as well as wifi is working good